# SSRS Tablix Cell Calculation based on RowGroup Value - Total Column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

This is a follow up to my [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280298/ssrs-tablix-cell-calculation-based-on-rowgroup-value).  The solution worked well for individual months but for the fiscal year total, is there a way to sum up aggregate so I can calculate the percentage, as described in the previous post?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to create a new dataset with data rolled up for the Fiscal Year and using the LookUp Expression to show that data on the grid.

For data that doesn't aggregate with SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, etc. I found I had to calculate the aggregates in SQL for most items, while summing up component data for more complicated equations (weighted averages, percentages of RMA over total sales, etc.).